# vite - module is not defined error in 3rd party npm package

Tags: vite

Here's the error I'm getting inside of my application:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at isHotReloading2 (isHotReloading.js:2:20)
    at Form3.UNSAFE_componentWillMount (createReduxForm.js:511:16)
```

and here's what the error looks like in the chrome inspector:
[image: error in chrome inspector]

I can't easily change the course code of redux-form (which is no longer being maintained) and neither can I remove it from my application. Is there a way to work around this error?

I've tried the following fixes in the vite.config.js file to no avail. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: possible fixes]

Comment: Did you try to exclude the dependency from pre-bundling? https://vitejs.dev/config/dep-optimization-options.html#optimizedeps-exclude. This helped in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this thankfully got fixed in redux-form v8.3.10

https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/pull/4723

So just upgrade to that!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue with Redux-form and fixed it as follows.

Create a file with the following

```
const isHotReloading = () => false;

export default isHotReloading;
```

In your vite.config file add the following to resolve.alias

```
{
    find: './util/isHotReloading',
    replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './PATH_TO_FILE_ABOVE/reduxFormHotReload.js'),
},
```

This will disable the hot reload update functionality all together, so maybe you could improve the function above, but I didn't worry about it.

Comment: this is not working for me

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with the `jsonwebtoken` package.